# Using an Argument to a Generic Type in Another Generic Type

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

The title might be a bit ambiguous as I'm not sure how to phrase what I am trying to do exactly.

I would like to replicate something like this pattern from C++ in python:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    using t = T;  // Alias T so it can be used in Bar
};


template<typename T>
struct Bar
{
    // The type T from Foo<T> can be used as a return type here
    typename T::t fn()
    {
        // do something that returns T::t
    }
};

int main(){
    // x is determined to be a float
    auto x = Bar<Foo<float>>().fn();
};
```

In terms of python, I would like to specialize a generic type `Bar[T]` with another specialized type `Foo[T]` and then use the type that was used to specialize `Foo` to type hint in `Bar`.

Something like

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    ...

class Bar(Generic[Foo[T]]): # <-- This is illegal
    def fn(self) -> T:
        ...

# In the following, I would like the type checker to know that x is an int.
x = Bar[Foo[int]]().fn()
```

I know that this relationship can be deduced when creating instances of `Bar` if we have something like

```
class Bar(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, foo: Foo[T]):
        ...
```

but that doesn't really fit my current problem.

I would rather like to be able to create a family of specializations `Foo[T]`, `Bar[T]`, `Baz[T]`, etc without having repeat `T` many times.  In my real use case the types are more like `Foo[R, S, T]` and repeating the types is quite tedious and error prone and, conceptually, classes `Bar`, `Baz`, etc are thought of not as depending on a type `T` but rather a particular type of `Foo[T]`.

So it would be nice to have the ability to do something like

```
MyFoo = Foo[int]
MyBar = Bar[MyFoo]
MyBaz = Baz[MyFoo]
```

Comment: You can try to use `typing.Union`, such as `Union[int, str]`

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Python's current typing syntax, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the mypy documentation, I came across this: [Advanced uses of self-types](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/more_types.html#advanced-uses-of-self-types)

By using a `TypeVar` bounded by `Foo` in `Bar` we can specify that `Bar` is parameterized by something `Foo`-like.  Then, within individual methods we can annotate `self` with the nested type `Bar[Foo[T]]` causing `T` to be bound to the parameter of the parameterizing `Foo` parameterizing `Bar`.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

class Foo(Generic[T]):
    ...

# You may want to make `S` covariant with `covariant=True` 
# if you plan on using subclasses of `Foo` as parameters to `Bar`.
S = TypeVar("S", bound=Foo)

class Bar(Generic[S]):
    def fn(self: Bar[Foo[T]]) -> T:
        ...

# Below, when binding `fn`, `self` is recognized as 
# being of type `Bar[Foo[int]]` which binds `T` as `int` 
# and hence the return type is also `int`.
x = Bar[Foo[int]]().fn()
```

What I have been unable to figure out is how to annotate an attribute of `Bar` using the parameter `T` in `Bar[Foo[T]]`.  Something like

```
class Bar(Generic[Foo[T]]):  # Still invalid.
    item: T
```

sill doesn't work as.

However, this can be worked around by wrapping the attribute in a property

```
class Bar(Generic[S]):
    _item: Any
    
    @property
    def item(self: Bar[Foo[T]]) -> T:
        return self._item
```

at the cost of the type hint for `_item` being imprecise.